# Not able to fetch list of files and folder names for a given directory using MongoDB Projection/Aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-projection

**I have a JSON-structured data for a filesystem:**

```
{
    id : 1,
    filename : "File-1",
    children : [
        {
            id: 2,
            filename: "File-2"
            children : [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    filename: "File-3",
                    children: [
                        {
                            id: 5,
                            filename: "File-5",
                            children: null;
                        }
                    ];
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    filename: "File-4",
                    children: null;
                },
                {
                    id: 6,
                    filename: "File-6",
                    children: null;
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

This is a document present in the MongoDB. And I wanted to fetch the list of files and folder names for a given directory, not the one which is present inside the folder.

**Let me explain with an example:**

**If the user input is:** File-1/File-2

**The response should be a list of files/folder names:**
[ File-3, File-4, File-6 ]

**Note:** File-5 should be excluded.

I tried using MongoDB projection/aggregation but could not able to achieve it.
Could anyone please help to achieve this requirement?

Comment: can file 5 also have another child?

Comment: @varman yes it can..